# Mapbox: Runtime styling for custom NavigationView

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I created a custom NavigationView Fragment which I am calling from my MapView Fragment. Following the example in the documentation I tried to use runtime styling within the navigationView.xml file by creating a custom style. So far I can customize every element while starting my turn-by-turn navigation within my custom NavigationView apart from the map view itself.

At my MapView Fragment I am already using the light- color theme and it renders the map colors as expected.

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            ...
            mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9"/>
```

However I am using a styleUrl the same way in my navigationView.xml which doesn't have any effect on the graphical presentation of the turn-by-turn navigation view. It still shows the default -day navigation styling. But in case of consistency I would like to have the same styling for my map view as well as for my navigation view.

```
<com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
           ...
            app:navigationLightTheme="@style/CustomNavigationViewLight"/>
```

In my style.xml file I added the following line as described:

```
<!-- Map style -->
        <item name="navigationViewMapStyle">@string/navigation_guidance_light</item>
```

In my string.xml file I added the following line with the stylesUrl:

```
<string name="navigation_guidance_light"
        translatable="false">mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9</string>
```

As the MapView instance within NavigationView is a private member I have no direct possibility to access it and add a UrlStyle programmatically. Is there any better solution?

Actual turn-by-turn navigation view:

[Actual Navigation View Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbxzu.jpg)

I would like to add the same light style to my navigation view as displayed beyond.

[Desired Navigation View Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXPxi.png)

Comment: how about creating a custom style and adding it in your maps https://www.mapbox.com/studio/ ?

Comment: More info about Mapbox styles here https://www.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/styles/#style-editor

Comment: @nimi0112 thanks for the hint, I saw this already but I hoped I could just use what is already there in case of styling themes. I am not sure if this is an issue of how my custom style is created as I can add the StyleUrl to my MapView within the xml file and it renders exactly as expected, but somehow doesn't make any change to my NavigationView.